# Distance from $x^{2021}$ to $P_{2020}$, the set of continuous polynomial functions of degree $\leq 2020$ on [-1,1]

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

The question is stated as follows:
Let $C([−1, 1])$ be the space of all continuous real-valued functions $f (x)$ with $x \in [−1, 1]$. Let $\|f(x)\|_{\infty} := \displaystyle \sup_{x \in [-1,1]} |f(x)|$. Find the distance from the point $p = x^{2021}$ to the space $P_{2020}$ of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2020.

My interpretation of this problem is that I'm supposed to find the smallest distance from $x^{2021}$ to any polynomial of degree $\leq 2020$ (distance between two polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is determined by $\displaystyle \max_{x \in [-1,1]} \|f(x) - g(x)\|$). I considered using a proof by contradiction and assuming that the distance was some nonzero $k$, and simply adding a constant to $f(x)$ to make it equal to $g(x)$ at the point where the distance between them is $k$ (this would make the distance 0 at that $x$-value). The obvious problems with this approach are that 1) the distance between the polynomials shouldn't be zero, and 2) adding a constant doesn't ensure that the $x$ value that maximizes the distance remains the same.

I've also thought about constructing some kind of sequence of functions that get as close as possible to $x^{2021}$, but I'm not quite sure how I would go about doing this. Any advice on how to approach this? For context, I've been learning about norms and Banach spaces in lecture.